# PHP set dynamic array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following `key/value` from my `$_POST` variable:

```
Array
(
     'translations_0_comment' => 'Greetings from UK'
)
```

What I would like is to set this values to the following array

```
$data[translations][0][comment] = 'Greetings from UK';
```

So the idea is that I can have anything in my `KEY` values, and from that I will populate an array.

Is there any safe way to do this without using `eval()` ?

All help is appreciated.

*UPDATE:*

this would be the idea with `eval()`

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $dataValue) {            
    $a = explode("_", $key);
    $builder = '$object';
    foreach ($a as $value) {
        $builder.='['.$value.']';
    }
    $builder.=' = '.$dataValue.';';
    eval($builder);         
}
```

Comment: Just curious: how would `eval()` help anyway?

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario, just updated my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
function set_value($object, $paths, $value, $index){

    $key = $paths[$index];

    $sub_object = $object[$key];
    if (!is_array($sub_object)){
        $object[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        $index = $index+1;
        $object[$key] = set_value($sub_object, $paths, $value, $index);
    }
    return $object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) is what you are looking for

Example

In your form which generate the $_POST data rename the input attribute as follows

```
<input name="data[translations][0][comment]" />
```

and now your `$_POST['data']` will be an array

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` is what you need:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($postData as $key => $val) {
    $explodedKey = explode('_', $key);
    $data[$explodedKey[0]][$explodedKey[1]][explodedKey[2]] = $val;
}
```

No need to use `eval()`.

Comment: Hm... but I can have have any number of _ in the KEY, so it is not limited to 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $keys => $val) {
    $keys_list = explode('_', $keys);
    $link = &$data;
    foreach ($keys_list as $key) {
        $link[$key] = $val;
        $link = &$link[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one sir.

```
$array = array
(
     'TRY_THIS_ONE_SIR_PLEASE_THANKS' => 'Greetings from UK'
);

$array1 = array_keys($array);
$arrValue = array_values($array);
$array1 = explode("_", $array1[0]);

$ctr = count($array1);
for($i=0; $i<$ctr; $i++)
{
    $start .= "array(\"".$array1[$i]."\" => ";
    $end .=")";
} 
$start = $start ."\"".$arrValue[0]."\"".$end;

eval("\$arr = $start;");

print_r($arr);
```